# What's the difference between records and tuples in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is there any difference between records and tuples that is not just a syntactic difference ?

Is there a performance difference ?

Is the implementation the same for tuples and records ?

Do you have examples of things that can be done using tuples but not with records (and 
conversely) ?

Comment: What brings about this kind of question? They lend themselves to different applications. I wouldn't be concerned about performance at this stage. The implementation is not "the same", because … they're different things.

Comment: If they're different things, then do you have examples of things that can be done using tuples but not with records (and conversely) ? I ask this question because the two things you say are different seem very similar to me.

Comment: Define "can be done". Forgive the patronising tone, but anything can be done with a Turing machine. Records just provide easier access, i.e. you don't need to deconstruct the entire thing just to get at one element. They are better documenting, and along with easier access, allow easier updating of refs within with the `mutable` keyword and `<-` syntax.

Comment: I mean, you'd agree that lists and tuples are different, right? Yet they could be used identically, if you were silly.

Comment: @Len: that's apples and oranges. Thomash's question is perfectly valid. Type-theoretically, both tuples and records are just product types (one unlabelled, the other labelled, but that's a relatively minor difference), with constant width but heterogenous components. It is indeed somewhat redundant that OCaml has both (plus object types as a third form of product). Lists however are recursive sum types, with unspecified length but homogeneous components, so something entirely different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Floats fields in float-only records or arrays are stored unboxed, while no such optimization applies to tuples. If you are storing a lot of floats and only floats, it is important to use records -- and you can gain by splitting a mixed float/other datastructure to have an internal float-only record.

The other differences are at the type level, and were already described by Andreas -- records are generative while tuples pre-exist and have a structural semantics. If you want structural records with polymorphic accessors, you can use object types.

Answer (score 21):

Modulo syntax they are almost the same. The main semantic difference is that tuples are structural types, while records are nominal types. That implies e.g. that records can be recursive while tuples cannot (at least not without the -rectypes option):

```
type t = {a : int, b : unit -> t}  (* fine *)
type u = int * (unit -> u)         (* error *)
```

Moreover, records can have mutable fields, tuples can't.

FWIW, in OCaml's sister language SML, tuples *are* records. That is, in SML (a,b,c) is just syntactic sugar for {1=a,2=b,3=c}, and records are structural types as well.

Comment: Re: mutable fields, there's nothing stopping you from defining `type v = int * int ref` then saying `snd some_v := 90210`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know something about performance differences?

Comment: @Len: yes, but that actually is a record nested into a tuple in OCaml, where 'a ref = {mutable content: 'a}. That is, you have an extra indirection. Ultimately, mutability is always tied to records.

Comment: @Thomash: Performance-wise there should be no difference at all. Both are compiled to the same thing.

Comment: An exception is made for floating point values.  A record containing only floating point fields will be compiled to a more efficient form (floats are unboxed) than a tuple with only floating point elements (floats are boxed).

Comment: @hcarty: Indeed, I should have mentioned that.