# '==' type and pattern matching - wait for the other recursive calls and do nothing on a case

Tags: syntax, functional-programming, ocaml

I have two questions concerning OCaml.
Firstly, what does the `==`  means when defining a `type`.

For example you can see at the end of [this page](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/definitions_de_types-fra.html) the following code:

```
type compteur == int;;
```

Then what is the difference with:

```
type compteur = int;;
```

Moreover I have an other question concerning pattern matching. 
How to say that you want to return nothing on a case.

For example let's say I have a function `f` that returns a boolean:

```
let rec f v = function 
     | t when t<v -> true
     | t when t > v -> f (t-1)
     | t when t = v -> (* here a code to say that you do nothing, and wait for the other recursive call *)
```

Comment: Not sure but I think `==` in the type definition is a typo. And normally when `you want to return nothing` you use exceptions or `option` type.

Comment: @vonaka Ok thank you ! Btw do you know what is the advantage between : `type a = int*int` and `type a = {c:int; d:int}` ?

Comment: This question is unrelated with your post, so in future when you have another question ask it in separate post. But yep, answering your question, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481910/whats-the-difference-between-records-and-tuples-in-ocaml#10482435).

Comment: Ok, mb, but thank you !

Comment: The link in your question refers to Caml Light, not OCaml. In Caml Light, `==` was used for type abbreviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type compteur == int` is a syntax error. The only valid way to define a type alias is with `=`, not `==`. It's just a typo on the page you linked.

> How to say that you want to return nothing on a case.

The only way to return nothing from a function would be to exit the program, raise an exception or loop (or recur) infinitely. Otherwise a function always returns a value.

> here a code to say that you do nothing, and wait for the other recursive call

What other recursive call? In the case that `t = v` only the code for that case will run. There is no other code to wait on.

Comment: Thank you ! So when I define something like :` type a = int*int;` Then how can I create a variable of type a ? `let b = a(3,3);` doesn't work... btw is there any advantage between a definition type like : `type a = int*int` and `type a = { c: int; d:int}` ? I was looking for some kind of priority in the pattern matching, like : treat this case before the other.

Comment: Because If there is a case I don't want to treat, and return nothing on a case or the void value (), it's impossible ...

Comment: @obla It'd be just `let b = (3, 3)`. A type alias is indistinguishable from the original type, so there'd be no discernible difference between `a` and `int*int`. That includes the fact that values of the type are created exactly the same way.

Comment: @obla The priority of a pattern match is determined by the order. That is, the patterns that come first are checked first (and we take the first pattern that matches successfully), but in your example all the cases are mutually exclusive, so priority doesn't factor into it.

Comment: @obla "Because If there is a case I don't want to treat, and return nothing on a case or the void value (), it's impossible" All cases have to have the same type. If you want to return `()` from one case, you need to return it from all cases. Otherwise your function could return different types for different inputs and OCaml does not support that. I'm still not clear what exactly you want your code to achieve. What would you want the result of calling `f 42 42` to be?

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Actually `f` was just a dumb example. I am working on binary trees, and sometimes there is in my pattern matching a case I don't want to handle, but the problem is that I have warnings. But I think, I should do what you said in answer : just raise an exeption like : `raise exeption "A case I don't want to handle`

Comment: @obla For this case you can use `failwith "A case I don't want to handle"`